# How to use choropleth map function with python plotly library to visualize by continent?

Tags: python, geolocation, plotly, location, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth map to visualize each continent's total pageviews from dataframe but plotly library function'S locationmode parameter does not have it.Is there any way to solve this problem ? When I use the 'country names' for the locationmode it does not work.

```
st.subheader("Continent's Total Pageviews Choropleth Map")
fig2 = go.Figure(data= go.Choropleth(
locations= df1['continent'],
z = df1['total_pageviews'].astype(float),
locationmode = 'country names',
colorscale = 'Reds',
colorbar_title = "Total Pageviews",
))
fig2.update_layout( width = 1100 , height = 500 )
st.write(fig2)
```

Comment: how can run your code? please share your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- get GEOJSON of continents
- build a **geopandas** dataframe,  integrate the **page views** data
- simple **mapbox** plot

```
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

cont = requests.get(
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/91ea5cc9474286c72838/raw/59421ff9b268ff0929b051ddafafbeb94a4c1910/continents.json"
)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(cont.json())

gdf = gdf.assign(
    total_pageviews=np.random.randint(10 ** 7, 10 ** 9, len(gdf))
).set_index("CONTINENT")

px.choropleth_mapbox(
    gdf,
    geojson=gdf.geometry,
    locations=gdf.index,
    color="total_pageviews",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    color_continuous_scale="Reds",
    opacity=0.5,
    zoom=1,
).update_layout(margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "b": 0, "t": 0})
```

Comment: Thank you so much  , it worked fine I handled bit for geopandas installation and data manipulation to fix data-location , thanks again sir.

Comment: But in the geoJSON file there are both oceania and australia exist  by the way antarctica is missing.

Comment: I just googled for geojson continents and boom first result.   if you want other features find some geojson that meets your requirements and the approach is the same.  Antarctica is there just no zoom.  In my understanding of continents defined by continental plates,  Australia is a continent :-)